# Experiencing tears/glitches in my screen on Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04

Tags: graphics, tearing

For around 1 week so far I've noticed screen tears and other graphical glitches.

I have only noticed them while browsing (in Chrome and Firefox), either while watching streams in flash or html5 format (Netflix, YouTube, twitch, even gifs) or scrolling through a big screen of text or images.

Here are some examples of the glitches I see:

[image: screen drawn with bad horizonal alignment in one place]

[image: tear]

[image: tear]

[image: tear]

This is really annoying, since it is constant and is very distracting.

The issue started on Ubuntu 16.04, and I did a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu 17.04 thinking this would solve it, but it didn't.

Currently I am running Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit version on an old Dell Studio 17. This is the gpu info:

```
lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165]
```

I have tried 4 different kernel versions and the issue persists:

1. 4.6.3
2. 4.10.0
3. 4.11.12
4. 4.12.3

I don't know what to do to fix this, can you guys help me figure this out?

Comment: I've also experience similar graphical glitches, and even worse, when scrolling my web browser and watching videos. It even happens in the TTY. I just want to know, how did you take those screenshots capturing the tears?

Comment: @takatakatek I used the print screen function while playing videos, I took a ton and I was lucky to capture the tears in some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Install Compizconfig Settings Manager

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

In there, go to:

**General -> Composite -> Unredirect Match**

and add Google-chrome to the list. Be careful with CCSM - it's very powerful.

Comment: I did a backup of the default values and removed all the Chrome/Chromium and Firefox since it was being excluded and then I added Firefox and Chrome.

The question I have is, do I need to activate Composite or just adding the applications to the list is more than enough?

Comment: Well I did what you said but it didn't work for me. Same results with Composite enabled and disabled.

Thanks for the suggestion though.